# Bookmarklet Window.Location change not behaving

Tags: javascript, regex, bookmarklet

Sorry folks, I've been poking around StackOverflow for awhile but can't seem to garner enough information to fix my problem here. I'm not very adept with regex, or the use of javascript in bookmarklets. Hoping someone can help me fix this little problem.

I would like this:

> http://www.example.com/a/b/c/d/review?set=123456

To become this:

> "     "     "     "     "    /close?set=123456

Obviously placeholder information (not that hard to figure out what it's for haha), but the sections abcd are ALWAYS there and always the same, it's just the very end piece that changes while retaining the variable number at the end.

Here's what I have that doesn't work:

```
javascript:window.location=window.location.href.replace(/.+set=(\d+).+/i,'http://www.example.com/a/b/c/d/close?set=$1');
```

Every time I use the bookmarklet, instead of loading the page properly, it just falls flat and does nothing. However if I manually change the correct piece of the URL, it behaves properly... I think I'm doing something wrong and I think it's very simple.

The numbers at the end are variable in both value and number. Every other piece remains static.

Any advice?

Comment: For clarity's sake, the quotation marks are just filler space. I don't want to change the first URL at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quicker but no regex:

```
javascript:window.location.href = window.location.href.replace("review?","close?");
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to replace

```
/.+set=(\d+).+/i
```

with

```
/.+set=(\d+).*/i
```

The `+` matches one or more of whatever precedes it.

Comment: I'm going to test this now. It's something I'm using repeatedly ad-nauseum, and I have a large crop of test data to try it out on. So far? Looks like it's working perfectly. I'll get back to you in about 10 minutes :)

Comment: Working PERFECTLY. Thank you. I'd rep you up but my own rep is too low :(